# Always run X11 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, xorg, cygwin-x

I have Cygwin-X installed on my Windows 10 machine.

When I run XLaunch, everything starts up fine.

What I would like, though, for X11 to start up, and stay running, when Windows starts, and to continue running, even when there are no X/11 applications running.

That is, what I don't want is to have the X11 server tied to an xterm, so that it shuts down if the xterm is closed.

Answer (score 0):

#### What I would like is for X11 to start up, and stay running, when Windows starts

Look for the shortcut "XWin Server" and copy it to the appropriate startup folder.

The shortcut runs the following command:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\run.exe --quote /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c "cd; /usr/bin/startxwin"
```

If you need to create the shortcut yourself then modify the directory locations as appropriate.

[image]